# How to get @Postconstruct with Spring batch in web container?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch

Currently I am trying to get my script to run on a tomcat server by using the basic web container guidelines for spring-batch-boot from the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html 
The script was working correctly as a jar file before modifications to the main class but when I try converting it to a servlet I am having issues with my `@PostConstruct` starting only on server startup. This code sets application.properties to `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` and has a controller of

```
@Controller
public class JobLauncherController {
   @Autowired
   JobLauncher jobLauncher;

   @Autowired
   Job job;

   @RequestMapping("/jobLauncher.html")
   public void handle() throws Exception{
      jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
}
```

With The main Application to start the servlet for tomcat as

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(BatchApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);

}
```

The problem is that my job uses custom item readers and writers that initializes it before running it using `@PostConstruct`. It runs the @PostConstruct at server startup which is what helps initialize the beans for writing. 
My item readers/writers look like this

```
public class CustomReader extends ItemStreamSupport implements ItemReader<Acct>, ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<Acct> {
    //basic autowiring
    private int nextAcctIndex;
    private List<Acct> acctsList = new ArrayList();

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() throws IOException {
        //logic to parse files
        acctsList = Collections.unmodifiableList(acctsList);
        nextAcctIndex = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Acct read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        // System.out.println("Start Read");

        Acct nextAcct = null;
        if (nextAcctIndex < acctsList.size()) {
            nextAcct = acctsList.get(nextAcctIndex);
            nextAcctIndex++;
            //System.out.println(nextAcct);
        }
```

The BatchConfiguration calls everything like most examples as
`@Bean public
 IteamReader<Acct> CustomReader(){ return new CustomReader();}`

My question is am I going about this the wrong way or is there a way to make it so the `@PostConstruct` is able to be called only when the Controller request for it?

Comment: Your reader/writers with this should be step or job scoped. Apparently you create them as singletons. But why do you do that in an `@PostConstruct` method? There is no such need...

Comment: What are you trying to do with `@PostConstruct`?  Why use it vs the regular spring annotations?

Comment: That was it. I am new to spring and was not sure what exactly I was trying to ask but StepExecutionListener was perfect with BeforeStep and AfterStep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use

```
@BeforeStep
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    init();
}
```

`@PostConstruct` is used to initialize once after `applicationContext` is loaded.
In your case you want to run this initialization every time job is running (you don't want data to be leaked across different jobs, right?)